# Error importing shapefile into PostgreSQL using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

I installed both PostgreSQL and PostGIS. But I am not able to import a shapefile to the database? It gives an error, "Shapefile import failed". What am I doing wrong?

I opened the file with ArcGIS and did not find multiple gid fields.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to GISSE.  Will you please add the error message as text and in English please?  Check out the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the best way to ask questions and get answers on this site.

Comment: Did you add the postgis extension  to the postgres  database?

Comment: Since ArcGIS tools can copy feature classes to PostgreSQL databases with PostGIS enabled *without* an enterprise geodatabase enabled, you might try creating a login, a schema to match the login name, and a connection file, then using that connection file as a target workspace, which could help you to triangulate your issue. Without a clearer indication of what is happening, we won't likely be able to help.